# Name one text editor that can open zip files besides EMACS/Vim

Tags: windows, zip, editor, gzip

I have searched for, downloaded and tried a lot of different editors but it seems that only EMACS and Vim are capable of opening zip files. As a noob i find both intimidating, as would be countless other programmers.

Does anyone know of an editor besides these 2 that can open zip files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be OLDSKOOLED at http://oldskooled.a2hosted.com/

It's console based, has a minimalist design but extremely functional.
Able to open ZIP, GZ and Z archives even if they're nested inside other zip files.

I absolutely love its quick folding..and the Ctrl-W paste from clipboard history.

So, there are only 3! text editors that can open zip files in the whole wide world ?